# HTML data to SharePoint list

Tags: list, javascript, html, json

I have an aspx page with JS parser which parse JSON to HTML. Can I get parsed information and load it to SharePoint list?

Comment: Could you provide more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint exposes WebServices which you can use to load information to SharePoint from External Systems.

Since you specifically requested for List Item Add below service can be used

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ryanrogers/2004/10/08/adding-new-list-items-using-the-lists-asmx-web-service/

You can also check the REST endpoints

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292552.aspx